# How can I programmatically group table column variables MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-table

If I create a table with:

```
t = table(magic(3));
```

I get a table with a Singular Variable Name

[image: Table with Singular Variable Name]

However if I:

```
a = magic(3);
T = array2table(a);
```

Then I get a table with Three Variable Names:

[image: Table with Three Variable Names]

If I try to group the columns by sending it only one variable name for the table:

```
T.Properties.VariableNames = {'OneName'};
The VariableNames property must contain one name for each variable in the table.
```

In the second situation, there is an option to combine the columns into one column manually by highlighting the columns and right clicking on the mouse.

[image: Manually Combined 3 Variables into 1 Variable]

How can I programmatically group the three variables to become one Variable as in the first example if I already created the matrix `a` ?

EDIT:

*as in the first example if I already created the table `a` ?

I am using R2017b

Based on the comment below, I am asking how to do `mergevars` prior to R2018a.

In the above example, I would be able to group them into one variable with:

```
t = table(a);
```

In other words, I hoped to create multiple multicolumn variables.  In other-other words, to do `mergevars` prior to R2018a.

Comment: I don't get it. You ask _... if I already created the matrix `a`_. But given `a` you can just use `t = table(a)` as in the first code snippet

Comment: If you mean create `t` _from `T`_, see [`mergevars`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mergevars.html) (requires R2018a)

Comment: Just use `table(a)` instead of `array2table(a)`. The whole point of `array2table` is that the array columns are separated into individual table columns.

Comment: @Luis Mendo Thank you Luis.  I had not heard of `mergevars` in my googling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the table `T` has been created with a variable name for each column, the column values could be extracted, and then assigned back to `T`:

```
b = T{:, 1:2};
c = T{:, 3};
T = table(b, c);
```

[image]